# Why is the typeid name of this factory function built CRTP class not as expected?

Tags: c++

I have a factory function that creates an instance of the Object class. The Object class inherits from std::enable_shared_from_this. The factory function creates an interim class that inherits Object to build it.

When I output the typeid.name() of the Object class, I get an unexpected result.

The complete example is here and has been tested with gcc-4.9.2 and clang-3.5:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d06047865a3bb477

Here is the factory function:

```
class ObjectBuilder
{
public:
    template<typename T, typename... Args>
    static std::shared_ptr<T> make_object(Args&&... args)
    {
        struct Access : public T {
            Access(Args&&... args) :
                T(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {
                // empty
            }
        };

        // call T's constructor
        std::shared_ptr<T> ob =
                std::make_shared<Access>(
                    std::forward<Args>(args)...);

        return ob;
    }
};

template<typename T, typename... Args>
static std::shared_ptr<T> make_object(Args&&...args)
{
    return ObjectBuilder::make_object<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Here is the Object class:

```
class Object : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Object>
{
    friend class ObjectBuilder;

public:
    virtual ~Object() {}

    std::type_info const & GetTypeInfo()
    {
        return typeid(*this);
    }

protected:
    Object() {}
};
```

Constructing the object and outputting its typeid name:

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> obj = make_object<Object>();
std::cout << demangle(obj->GetTypeInfo().name()) << std::endl;
```

I expected an output like:

```
ObjectBuilder::make_object<Object>()::Access
```

Instead the demangled output was:

```
std::shared_ptr<Object> ObjectBuilder::make_object<Object>()::Access
```

Why is there a std::shared_ptr at the beginning? What does it signify?

Also an interesting/maybe related side note: clang is able to demangle the output, but gcc isn't. The mangled output is:

```
ZN13ObjectBuilder11make_objectI6ObjectIEEESt10shared_ptrIT_EDpOT0_E6Access
```

Comment: Note that the return type of a *function template* (specialization) is part of its signature. You can have two different function templates (overloaded) where only the return type differs. (So I guess they use the return type here as part of the name of the nested type.)

Comment: Woah! That makes sense! I guess its obvious that the first part of the typeid name is the return type, I have no idea why I didn't make the connection. If you post your comment as an answer, I can accept it. A bit strange that gcc can't demangle the name though

Comment: To me, it looks like [gcc is also able to demangle the name](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81b11b33c6f132df), though that might be version-dependent.